# Start timer after button click

Tags: android

I want to start timer after clicking on Button and poll for every 3 secs.

I am using following code.

```
private EditText url;
private Button submit;
private TextView error;
String some_URL;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);

    loadviews();
 handler=new Handler();
 submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        some_URL="http://"+url.getText().toString();
              getStatus();
        }

    }
});
private void getStatus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Class_Poll().execute(some_URL);
                 error.setText("ID:"+ID+"\n"+
                    "Name:"+name+"\n" +
                    "Type:"+type+"\n"+
                    "Status:"+Status+"\n"+
                    "Content:"+Content);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
}

private void loadviews() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    url=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.url);

    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);
    error.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

}


private class Class_Poll extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

     private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Content=executeHttpRequest(some_URL);
         return null;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

         JSONObject jsonResponse;
         try {
             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

             ID=jsonResponse.optString("ID").toString();
             name=jsonResponse.optString("Name").toString();
             type=jsonResponse.optString("Type").toString();
             Status=jsonResponse.optString("Status").toString();

             error.setText("ID:"+ID+"\n"+
                        "Name:"+name+"\n" +
                        "Type:"+type+"\n"+
                        "Status:"+Status+"\n"+
                        "Content:"+Content);

         } catch (JSONException e) {

             error.setText(e.toString());
         }

         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID:"+ID+" Name:"+name+" Type:"+type+" Status:"+Status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }

 public static String executeHttpRequest(String url)
 {
     HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
     try
     {

         URL httpUrl = new URL(url);
         urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) httpUrl.openConnection();
         urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
         urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,text/xhtml,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;");
         urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
         InputStream in = null;

         try
         {
             in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

         } catch (NullPointerException e)
         {
             Log.e("Check", "Request Failed, Check the url");
             return null;
         }

         if (in != null)
         {
             in = new BufferedInputStream(in);
             String response  = readStream(in);
             Log.e("Check", response + "");

             if (response != null && !response.isEmpty())
             {
                 // statusTrace.print(TAG, "Operation executed : " +
                 // isSuccess(response));
                 return response;
             } 
             else
             {
                 Log.e("Check", "Request Failed");
             }
         } else
             ;//statusTrace.print(TAG, "Request Failed");

     } catch (IOException e)
     {
         Log.e("Check", "Error : " + e.toString());
         //statusTrace.print("Error", "Network Error. Check connection and Tuxedo IP");
     }

     return null;
 }

     public static String readStream(InputStream in)throws IOException {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
     String read = br.readLine();

     while (read != null)
     {
         sb.append(read);
         read = br.readLine();
     }  
     return sb.toString();
 }
```

`error` is `TextView` in which I am displaying some Text.

And I am invoking web service in Asyntask. So it is not executing asynchtask for delay of 3 seconds after button click.

I don't know where know what is the problem exactly. It should execute actually, my textview is not getting updated for each 3 seconds.

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: Timer runs on a different thread you should not invoke AsyncTask from a background thread.

Comment: @Raghunandan: can you suggest me an alternative to this so that I can execute AsynchTask at after 3 secs of delay??

Comment: your delay is also 0. you get `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timer runs on a different thread you should not invoke AsyncTask from a background thread.

Please read Threading rules @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
public void scheduleAtFixedRate (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

Added in API level 1
Schedule a task for repeated fixed-rate execution after a specific delay has passed.

Parameters
task    the task to schedule.
delay   amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
period  amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.
Throws
IllegalArgumentException    if delay < 0 or period <= 0.
IllegalStateException   if the Timer has been canceled, or if the task has been scheduled or canceled.
```

Your delay is 0. See this  `}, 0, 3000);`

> can you suggest me an alternative to this so that I can execute
>   AsynchTask at after 3 secs of delay??

I assume you want to invoke asynctask after a 3 sec delay

You can use a Handler

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(): 
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                     // run something after 3 sec delay
              }                   
 }, 3000);
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private EditText url;
private Button submit;
private TextView error;
String Content;
String some_URL;
Handler handler;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);
    loadviews();
    handler=new Handler();
    submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        some_URL="http://"+url.getText().toString();
              getStatus();
        } 
     });
}
private void getStatus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            new Class_Poll().execute(some_URL);

        }
    }, 3000);
}


private void loadviews() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    url=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.url);

    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Submit);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);
    error.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

}

private class Class_Poll extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         String _response;
          try
          {
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet request = new HttpGet(arg0[0]);  
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
          HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

         return _response;
    }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         super.onPostExecute(result);
         JSONObject jsonResponse;
         try {
             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);

            String ID=jsonResponse.optString("ID").toString();
            String name=jsonResponse.optString("Name").toString();
            String type=jsonResponse.optString("Type").toString();
            String Status=jsonResponse.optString("Status").toString();

             error.setText("ID:"+ID+"\n"+
                        "Name:"+name+"\n" +
                        "Type:"+type+"\n"+
                        "Status:"+Status+"\n"+
                        "Content:"+Content);

         } catch (JSONException e) {

             error.setText(e.toString());
         }
     }    

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help... :) I did the changes suggested by you!! This code `Handler` is working if I am calling it from `onCreate` but I it is not working when I am calling it from Button click event. I want to start the polling class only after click event occurs.

Comment: @Rohit it will work no problem with that. post your updated code

Comment: @Rohit where have you initialized handler. post that code

Comment: I have updated the code in question. Plz have a look.. thnx :)

Comment: I have initialized it in onCreate

Comment: @Rohit post that code also. don't see anything wrong with current code

Comment: @Rohit i see nothing wrong it will work. what is the problem. The Asynctask will be invoked after 3 seconds. If you are waiting for result then there is a problem asynctask is asynchronous

Comment: @Rohit move `error.setText` to onPostExecute and check again

Comment: No... Its same as previous... I tried in PostExecute `error.setText` also I tried to print in `Log.e` but showing same result..

Comment: @Rohit that is simply not possible. What is that you are expecting. AFAIK it will invoke asynctask after 3 seconds. the problem is somewhere else. No doubt about that. You are dispalying results of asynctask in textview??. The problem is definitely not my suggestion

Comment: Might be If you say so... I am trying to figure it out. I am displaying results in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: in method `loadviews()` method I didnt posted that method. It just used for initializing `Button` and `TextView`

Comment: @Rohit likely that is the problem initialization of error.

Comment: It shows me other operations correctly in my App, only it is facing problem over here. So I don't think it is problem with initialization.

Comment: @Rohit check the edit it will work provided you have initialized your views properly